# Can't see my changes in IntelliJ in BitBucket

Tags: java, bitbucket

**I made a repository on Bitbucket and connected it with my local machine, but whenever I commit changes nothing happens in BitBucket.**

These are my steps (as described in tutorials online):

From BitBucket to a folder in Terminal: 
git clone https://myname@bitbucket.org/myname/myproject.git

Terminal says:
Cloning into 'myproject'...
remote: Counting objects: 3, done.
remote: Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
Unpacking objects: 100% (3/3), done.

Copied all files from my old project into the newly created “myproject” folder. 
Configured correct JDK, ran mvn install. Rebooted IntelliJ for configurations to activate. No errors or important messages appear, everything seems OK.

Enabled version control through VCS > Enable Version Control > Git.

Copied all files (except .idea, which I put in .gitignore) to default changelist.
Commit changes, all default settings.

Changes do not appear in BitBucket.. Any suggestions? I feel like I'm missing some vital (and probably obvious) step in connecting my machine to bitbucket.

Comment: Did you push to remote?

Comment: Go to VCS -> Git -> Push the changes to repo

Comment: I don't think so? Googling leads to a screen with cmd + shift + K. If I click "origin" I can "define remote" but I have no idea what to do here. Is this the way to go? How do I proceed?
**EDIT** Alright I think I figured some of this out. Experimenting a bit. Will update.

Comment: `origin` is the name of the remote you get by default when cloning.